# Check an int variable is null or is empty from the Database

Tags: java, jdbc

I am having a variable which is:

```
nocustomers = rs.getInt("CUST_TRAN_COUNT");
```

I would like to perform if it is null or not.

I tried

```
if (nocustomers ==null)
```

It showed an error.

How do I solve this?

---

My new modified code is:

```
try{

    query=" select * from SS_summary where txn_date = to_date ('"+asatdate+"','YYYY-MM-DD') ";
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    if (rs.next())
    {   


    nocustomers = rs.getInt("CUST_TRAN_COUNT");

    nocheques =rs.getInt("CHEQ_DELIVERED_MAIN");
    }

    if (rs.wasNull()) {
        out.println("NO DATA FOUND");
        }

%>
```

Comment: you can't check primitive datatypes for null (= null pointer), only pointers to objects. what is `rs` ? you have to check your ORM / SQL adapter for such a functionality

Comment: Whats the error and whats the datatype of this variable.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254435/can-an-int-be-null-in-java

Comment: @maas, you don't need to do a `rs.wasNull()` as `rs.getInt()` will return a `0` if data was null by default. Rather say, `if (nocustomers == 0) { out.println("NO DATA FOUND"); }`.

Comment: I'll have cancer because of looking at that example code :(

Answer (score 7):

`int` can't be `null`, because it's a primitive type.

For the same reason [`ResultSet.getInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29) can't return `null`.

You will need to call [`ResultSet.wasNull()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) right after your `getInt()` call to check if the value was `null`.

Note that since `int` can't be `null`, `nocustomer` will have a value even if the database value is `null`. `getInt()` is defined to return `0` when the DB value is `null`, so `nocustomers` will be `0`.

Comment: resultSet.wasNull() did not work and showed an error "java.sql.SQLException: No data read "

Comment: @maas: when did you call it? You **must** call `getInt()` *before* calling `wasNull()`. Please show us your code.

Comment: if (rs.next())
 {   
 

 nocustomers = rs.getInt("CUST_TRAN_COUNT");
}

if (rs.wasNull()) {
 out.println("NO DATA FOUND");
 }

Answer (score 3):

At compile time, the java compiler will complain with the following message:

```
incomparable types: int and <nulltype>
if (nocustomers  == null) {
      ^
```

That is because you can **never** do a null check on primitive types. Primitive types are assigned with default values (zero, for integers), **if** unassigned.

If you want to know if the value read was null, use the [`ResultSet.wasNull()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) method instead (**after** reading your integer value, see JavaDoc link provided):

```
nocustomers = rs.getInt("CUST_TRAN_COUNT");
if (rs.wasNull()) {
    nocustomers = -1; //Assuming, -1 means NULL.
}
```

Comment: Assigning `0` to `nocustomers` if `wasNull()` returns `true` is redundant, because that's already what `getInt()` will have returned in that case.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, that's true indeed. The OP shouldn't worry about checking a null, unless the OP wants to define `-1` as `null`. I changed my assignment value from `0` to `-1` for this example of using `ResultSet.wasNull()`.

Comment: if (rs.next()) { nocustomers = rs.getInt("CUST_TRAN_COUNT"); } if (rs.wasNull()) { out.println("NO DATA FOUND"); } it showed an error

Comment: @maas: please post your **full** code and the **full** stack trace (edit the question or post a new one).

Answer (score 2):

If the value was `NULL`, then 0 will be returned by `getInt`, and then you could call `wasNull` to check if it held a 0 or if it was a `NULL`.

See also: [wasNull()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29)

Comment: it showed an error "java.sql.SQLException: No data read "

Comment: @maas: make sure you called it only after `getInt` was called.

Comment: resultSet.wasNull() did not work and showed an error "java.sql.SQLException: No data read "

Answer (score 1):

you can use,

```
object obj = rs.getObject("CUST_TRAN_COUNT");
if (obj != null)
{
rs.getInt("CUST_TRAN_COUNT");
}
```

but in some cases (very rare) you can't call the getInt once you called the getObject, in that case you can simply use

```
int.parse(obj.toString())
```

Also, I think better way to do it is,

```
  int value = rs.getInt("CUST_TRAN_COUNT");
  boolean nullValue = rs.wasNull();
```

so if the db returned null, value would be 0 however nullValue will be true so that you can do the needful

Comment: What are those 'rare' cases?

Comment: The issue happened, with certain version of mysql driver where once I call getObject, the getInt for the same column throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`wasNull`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) method on your `ResultSet` or `RowSet`:

> Reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL `NULL`. Note that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try to read its value and then call the method `wasNull` to see if the value read was SQL `NULL`.