# Performing filtering over setter method?

Tags: java, oop, javabeans, setter, getter-setter

I need some filtering over setter methods and thinking modifying them, for instance:

```
class Dog{
    int speed;

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        if(speed < 100)
            this.speed = speed;
        else
            this.speed = 100;
    }
}
```

I don't remember any implementation like this and it is probably not legit(or improper at least). Instead of this, should i write additional setter method named `setFilteredSpeed(int speed)`, leaving `setSpeed(int speed)` as default? This way seems not breaking bean approach.

```
class Dog{
    int speed;

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public void setFilteredSpeed(int speed) {
        if(speed < 100)
            setSpeed(speed);
        else
            setSpeed(100);
    }
}
```

The third option is preparing seperate filter class like that:

```
class DogFilter{

    public int doSpeed(int speed) {
        if(speed < 100)
            return speed;
        else
            return 100;
    }
}

class Main(){
    public static void main(){
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setSpeed(DogFilter.doSpeed(165));
    }
}
```

it is common usage, I think; but second option seems closer to OOP approach. Which way is the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want to *completely* prevent invalid speeds, your first option is the correct approach

Comment: ok, modifying setter method is safe then. what if i set `null` the `speed` field if it is higher than 100? is it still safe for e.g. hibernate?

Comment: An `int` cannot be `null` in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254435/can-an-int-be-null-in-java

Comment: Throwing an exception might be a preferable solution.

Answer (score 1):

If `speed` should *never* be  higher that 100, the first solution will suffice. With the other two solutions you need to ensure that all classes that might set an invalid (too high) `speed` use the appropriate method, which is quite error-prone.