# Removing a JLabel after 10 seconds

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

If I have a JLabel, how do I remove it after 10 seconds? I want to be able to view the JLabel after I've removed it. I figure it might have something to do with `javax.swing.Timer` and `JLabel.setVisible(false)`.

Comment: You figured right. You want to start a timer, and when it's hit ten second, call the method to hide the `JLabel`. it's really that straight forward..

Comment: You can make use of pseudocode give for  [Swing timer not stopping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409868/swing-timer-not-stopping/14410163#14410163)

Comment: javax.swing.Timer and JLabel.setVisible(false). is right

Comment: Why bother with `setVisible(false)`?  I'd use `setText("")`.  Store the string if you want to view it later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
   final JLabel label = new JLabel("myLabel");

   int delay = 10000; //milliseconds
   ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           label.setVisible(false)
       }
   };
   new javax.swing.Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `label` should be an instance variable, or a `final` variable.