# How to make Jlabel visible and invisible using for loop in java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have the following code. I want to Make jLabel Visible and Invisible 4 times with 0.5Seconds delay for every loop. The code below is not working as expected.

```
String a = (String)jTextField1.getText();

  if(a.equals("")){

  for (int i = 0;i<=3;i++){
      try {
         jLabel1.setVisible(true);
          Thread.sleep(500);


          for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
          jLabel1.setVisible(false);
           Thread.sleep(500);
          }

      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

      }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Short answer, you don't. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for reasons why and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution

Comment: In general for timers you could use http://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-and-timertask-example-tutorial  . Java Timer class can be used to schedule a task to be run one-time or to be **run at regular intervals**. For swing use Swing's Timer.

Comment: @Willmore `java.util.Timer` really isn't appropriate for this problem, as you still need to take into consideration the non-thread safe nature of Swing, instead a Swing `Timer` would be a more appropriate solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you :)

Comment: you try  this link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596428/removing-a-jlabel-after-10-seconds