# error: variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I am unable to find the reason why I am getting:

> variable might not have been initialized

Example 1:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        int j;
        if (i == 10) {
            j = 20;
        }
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

> ```
> Test.java:11: error: variable j might not have been initialized
> System.out.println(j);
>                    ^
> 1 error
> ```

Example 2:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        int j;
        if (i == 10) {
            j = 20;
        } else {
            j = 30;
        }
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 20

My doubt is in the second example, how `j` is initialized?

Answer (score 3):

First case, if i != 10 j will not be initialized during

```
System.out.println(j);
```

In the second example j will always have a value at (i != 10 j will be 30)

```
System.out.println(j);
```

Mind the

```
**might not** be initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `int j;` you must have `int j = null;`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254435/can-an-int-be-null-in-java

An `int` cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

> in the second example, how j is initialized?

`j` is initialized because you have provided paths for all possible cases ...

- `i` is equal to `10` (the line `if(i == 10) {`)
- `i` is not equal to `10` (the line `} else {`)

No matter what, `j` will be initialized.

In your first solution, this was not the case.  If `i` is not equal to `10`, then j will not be initialized and Java does not like that.  Java does not care that `i` *is* equal to `10` in your logic, it just cares that there is a case where `j` may not be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

For local variables JVM won't provide any default values, we have to perform initialization explicitly, before using that variable.

In **Example 1:** 
There is no guarantee of initialization of local variable inside logical block at runtime, in your case you have only if statement **if it's not true then how the initialization is going to happen** , because of that you are getting this error.

In **Example 2:**
You have taken both if ,else statement so if condition is true the variable j will be initialized, if the condition is false then also j will be initialized. (In Example 2 either through **if or else** variable **j** will be initialized) because of that you are not getting any error.