# XSD conversion to Java is different for elements with minOccurs="0" than for elements with default occurence

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

Given 2 elements a and b in an XSD file. Both are of type int but the
difference is that a is having `minOccurs="0"` while b is not. So now when a Java class is generated out of this XSD, it contains a of type `Integer` while b is of type `int`. Please explain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:complexType name="SearchAB">
<xs:element name="a" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int">
<xs:annotation>`enter code here`
    <xs:documentation>a</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="b" type="xs:int">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>b</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>"
</xs:complexType>
```

Java class:

```
protected Integer a;
protected int b;
```

Comment: XSD looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:complexType name="SearchAB">
"<xs:element name="a"`` minOccurs="0" type="xs:int">
 <xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>a</xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="b" type="xs:int">
 <xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>b</xs:documentation>
 </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>"
</xs:complexType>

Comment: Please edit directly your code!

Comment: Which library you are using for Java code generation from XSD?

Comment: I am using wsimport command to generate the java classes. The sample part of xsd, I have given is part of xsd that is being in one wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

**Case b**
By default, `minOccurs="1"` and `maxOccurs="1"`.
Therefore, there is exactly one integer element (not fewer and not more), and it can be efficiently mapped to a simple `int`.

**Case a**
If an element has set `minOccurs="0"`, it is optional.
However, in Java, [an int cannot be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254435/can-an-int-be-null-in-java). So what value would you use to represent that the element is omitted? To deal with this possibility, the value is therefore stored as an `Integer` object, which *can* be `null`.
So, if the element is present, the `a` variable will have an integer value.
Otherwise, it is set to `null` to represent the omitted element.