# Is there a c#'s 'int?' equivalent in java?

Tags: java, types, nullable

Is there a nullable data type in java like int?, char?... in C#? Is there a way to create it as a class or something?

Need to create data type which will be able to hold null as well as number values.

Comment: What about `OptionalInt`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254435/can-an-int-be-null-in-java

Comment: In Java we use `Integer`. It's not completely equivalent because `Integer` is a class and `int?` is a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `int` is not nullable in Java
- But `Integer` is a class that contains a abstraction for `int` and can be `null`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Integer` since its nullable;

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

The same goes for `Boolean`.

basically they're class wrappers over the primitive types.