# Set an array element to Null - Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, integer

I need to create an array that holds integers. I did this:

```
int[] arr; 
arr = new int[5];
arr[0] = 10;
arr[1] = 20;
arr[2] = 30;
arr[3] = 40;
arr[4] = 50;
```

I need to shift the elements to left and set the last one to Null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) 
       arr[i]=arr[i+1];
   arr[arr.length-1]= Null
```

I did the above but I get an error. Please help me, I need to use null, not -1 or any other number. Perhaps I need to change my elements to object of Integer, but I dont know how to. Thanks

Comment: `int` is primitive type you can not add null to it. Use `Integer` instead.

Comment: `null` should also be with a lowercase 'n'

Answer (score 0):

Use the Integer type instead of primitive int. Integer can be null:
[was answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254463/4734653)