# How to manage when mybatis query returns null

Tags: sql-server-2008, mybatis

I have a mybatis query that returns a Long value depending on a parameter , but if the parameter doesn´t exist on the db it returns null, but I´m getting this exception:

```
Mapper method 'mysqlservermethod attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type (long).
```

How can I allow to return a null or what other thing can I do so, I can control in my java part for do something when the query returns null or let me know that there are no values that match the query, without doing a select count before?

MyBatys select header:

```
resultType="java.lang.Long" >
```

Comment: See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2254435/1261766). To receive `null`, the return type must be `java.lang.Long` instead of `long`.

Comment: I already have resultType="java.lang.Long" > but doesn´t work  @ave

Comment: As the error message says, it's the method's return type. You should post the complete Java and XML mapper method/statement.